# Not transparented layout

Tags: android, xml, transparency

i have fixed LinearLayout, like this

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="188dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:layout_weight="1.02">
```

That's how it looks like

[image]

and its transparented, but it must be white, so how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the background color to be what you want

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```